# How can I list users with a view permission on a resource in liferay?

Tags: permissions, liferay-6

I am using liferay 6.1 GA2

I would like to implement a feature allowing a user to send the content of a messageBaordmessage by email. I want to restrict that sendout to those that have view permission on the message.

How can I list the users that have view permission ?

Thanks,
Alain

Answer (score 0):

Liferay 6.1 GA2 already has the mailing feature built-in so assuming that doesn't meet your needs, I would think you could provide a new action to call into that feature as it already knows how to check view permissions on the MBMessage, MBThread and all parent MBCategories.

See com.liferay.portlet.messageboards.service.impl.MBMessageLocalServiceImpl for the implementation.